# Synthetica LAF JTabbedPane background color

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane, synthetica

Im using Synthetica LAF for Java. Im adding `JTabbedPane` with `JPanel` as tabs. When setting `JPanel.setBackground()` then for some tabs it works, for some not and for others the color appears when I resize the window of my GUI application. I tried to set it from the reference like:

```
JPanel tab = new MyTab();
tab.setBackground(Color.red);
tabbedPane.add(null, null, tab, null);
```

and I tried to set inside the MyTab class itself like:

```
this.setBackground(Color.red);
```

How can I get it to work for every tab?

Comment: Have you tried `tab.setOpaque(true)`?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm working around it by putting everything in a additional panel which fills the tab. But still would be nice to find a solution to the problem.